# Generate 3D surface from scattered or data points

Tags: matlab, 3d, cad, surface

Can anyone tell me how to generate a 3D surface model like CAD in Matlab ?
1.**Input:** Input is a collection of points with (x,y,z) where surface is present for an object(I'm using this for a 3D scanner where my inputs are (x,y,z) of surface)
2.Points should be displayed as a surface using some smooth interpolation.
3.More like surface generation from data points.
Thanks you.

Comment: `surf` is a good place to start, but I don't know what you are trying to ask. Please see [ask] and try to improve your question so that you get useful answers.

Comment: I doubt that you can plots equivalent to CAD in matlab. Normally CAD is a really advanced regarding graphics. However, if you want to display a surface, use `surf`. Regarding the data, If the points are uniformly sampled I think there is a file exchange on that, [smooth2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6298-smooth2). If the data is non uniform, I have not seen any built in for that (which does not mean that non exist). Then you will have to start with interpolating, eg `interp3` or `griddata` (and if this is good, maybe even stop there?).

Answer (score 0):

In order to plot surfaces, you can use `patch` function. However, you need along with the points the faces information. In `patch` a surface consists of polygons that is specified using 3 point, which is the face information.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIFdv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like you will be inputting discrete points located on the surface of the object, you will first want to create a Nonconvex Polygon based on the data using Matlab's `boundary` function.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html

You can then use the `trimesh` function to create the figure

This question shows the input data and what was produced using this method: [How do I create a 3D polygon/mesh over data points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351828/how-do-i-create-a-3d-polygon-mesh-over-data-points/40354626#40354626)