# How do I create a 3D polygon/mesh over data points?

Tags: matlab, 3d

I have an array of data points, `Points = [X,Y,Z]`, where `X`,`Y` & `Z` are `n-by-1` vectors. The `x`, `y` and `z` values are the result of a blackbox.

Here is an example of the points:

[image: 3D Points]

<sup>Fig. 3D Points</sup>

I want to generate something that looks like this:

[image: Mesh Drawing]

<sup>Fig. Mesh Drawing</sup>

If you can't make the drawing out, it's something like a deformed cylinder. A convex hull does not work because there are dips in the geometry that would be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was looking for was the `boundary` function in Matlab which creates a "shrink wrap" around the points.
It was hard to find this solution because while research & literature refers to this as a "Concave Hull", Matlab refers to it as "Nonconvex polygons" so searches for the former did not turn up anything.
[Meshed Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud1W2.png)